# How to add numbers in Solidity without getting an error?

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

(this is a funny joke question) `:-{`

I don't understand why this doesn't return 11.
I hope someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract a {
    uint256 numberA = 5;
    string operator = "+";
    uint256 numberB = 6;

    function add() external view returns(string memory)
    {
        return(numberA + operator + numberB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to specify the operator as a string.

Just remove the `operator +` part.

Also, adding two `uint256`'s returns a `uint256`. You will also need to change the return type of the `add()` function to `uint256` instead of `string memory`.